# How to get nodes in maya cmds who scale attributes aren't present in channel box

Tags: python, maya

I have this class and in the validation method I am getting all the required nodes I need. For any nodes, if the scale attributes aren't set to default I need to add them in `valid_failed_list`.

But for some element scale attributes aren't showing up in channel box. Is there any way I can skip those elements?

For example: [image]

I have tried using `attributequery` with hidden flag but that doesn't work as well.

```
class Scaled():
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scaled, self).__init__()
        self.fix_button = True


    def validation(self):
        print(self.__class__)

        self.valid_failed_list = []
        self.set_elements = cmds.ls(type="transform")
        self.required_nodes = []
        self.attrs = ['.scaleX', '.scaleY', '.scaleZ']
        

        self.jnt_grp_elements = cmds.ls("*:Jnt_Grp")
        self.geo_grp_elements = cmds.ls("*:Geo_Grp")
        self.constraint_elements = cmds.ls("*:*Constraint*")

        self.res = list(set(self.set_elements) - set(self.jnt_grp_elements))
        self.res = list(set(self.res) - set(self.geo_grp_elements))
        self.res = list(set(self.res) - set(self.constraint_elements))

        self.required_nodes.extend(self.res)


        for node in self.required_nodes:       
            scaleX = cmds.getAttr(node + '.scaleX')
            scaleY = cmds.getAttr(node + '.scaleY')
            scaleZ = cmds.getAttr(node + '.scaleZ')

            if scaleX != 1.0 or scaleY != 1.0 or scaleZ != 1.0:
                self.valid_failed_list.append(node)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the keyability of the channel with getAttr; if it's not keyable, it won't be in the channelBox:

`cmds.getAttr(node + ".scaleX", keyable=True)`